# Apache poi сводная таблица пример

Tags: java, apache-poi

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчанины. Возник, следующий вопрос.

С помощью java, с библиотекой apache poi я генерирую excel отчет. В книге я создаю два листа. На втором листе  я делаю таблицу которая состоит из ФИО, дата обращения, сумма, адрес проживания, район и т.д.
На основе второго листа, на первом листе у меня должна быть сводная таблица, которая группировала бы по району и суммировала сумму.
Не могли бы вы привести пример, как с помощью apache poi создавать сводную таблицу?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем заморачиваться? Придумайте другой способ, который будет легче. Например, я бы сделал вычисление в программе, и тупо в листы писал уже готовые значения, без заморочек совокупления разных листов и впихивания формул.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```
HSSFRow row6 = spreadSheet.createRow(6);
HSSFCell cell6 = row6.createCell((short) 0);
cell6.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
cell6 = row6.createCell((short) 1);
cell6.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
cell6 = row6.createCell((short) 2);
cell6.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
row6.setHeightInPoints(25);
cell6.setCellValue("до 5");
cell6 = row6.createCell((short) 3);
cell6.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
cell6.setCellValue("от 5 до 10");
```

Answer (score 1):

что бы создать лиcты

```
        `HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet spreadSheet = wb.createSheet("Лист 1");
        HSSFSheet spreadSheet1 = wb.createSheet("Лист 2");`
```

Answer (score 1):

Официальный пример здесь [CreatePivotTable.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java)

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

//Заполнение данных (реализация метода в CreatePivotTable.java)
setCellData(sheet);

AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:D4", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
CellReference position = new CellReference("H5");
// создание сводной таблицы
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(source, position);
// заполнение сводной таблицы
// строки
pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
// колонки
addColLabel(1);
// данные
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);
// фильтр
pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);

// сохранение в файле
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pivottable.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
wb.close();
```

Реализация `addColLabel` сделана по аналогии с `XSSFPivotTable.addRowLabel`

```
protected void addColLabel(int columnIndex) {
    AreaReference pivotArea = new AreaReference(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition()
            .getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().getRef(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
    int lastIndex = pivotArea.getLastCell().getCol() - pivotArea.getFirstCell().getCol();
    if (columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex > lastIndex)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    CTPivotTableDefinition pivotTableDefinition = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition();
    CTPivotFields pivotFields = pivotTableDefinition.getPivotFields();
    CTPivotField pivotField = CTPivotField.Factory.newInstance();
    CTItems items = pivotField.addNewItems();

    pivotField.setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotField.setShowAll(false);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
        items.addNewItem().setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
    items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
    pivotFields.setPivotFieldArray(columnIndex, pivotField);

    CTColFields axisFields = pivotTableDefinition.getColFields() == null ?
            pivotTableDefinition.addNewColFields() :
            pivotTableDefinition.getColFields();
    axisFields.addNewField().setX(columnIndex);
    axisFields.setCount(axisFields.sizeOfFieldArray());
}
```